# Have I solved this related rates trough question correctly?

Tags: calculus

I have answered a related rates question and wanted a look over to confirm the solution I have produced is right. I also do not mind any suggestions on other ways to solve these types of problems.

The question is as follows: A trough has a trapezoidal cross section, with a width at the bottom of 55cm, at the top 85cm, and height of 25cm. The total length of the trough is 300cm. If water is leaking from the trough at 800 cm^3 / s, at which rate is the height changing when the depth of the water is 11cm?

Here are the readable link to the solution that I have come up with : [http://imgur.com/dSe5qTA](https://imgur.com/dSe5qTA), [http://imgur.com/in6F7xX](https://imgur.com/in6F7xX)

Comment: The final related-rates equation appears to be correct.  (I removed the "optimization" tag, since this is not that sort of calculus problem.)

Comment: I really appreciate you having a look over and for fixing the tag. Thanks!

Comment: Your image links are 404s. Please use the official image uploader.